# Seeking to prove the equivalence of Perturbation series criteria

Tags: perturbation-theory

I am reading Avrachenkov's book "Analytic perturbation theory and its applications". One of the problems contained in the book is as follows:

If we substitute the series expansions
$$A(z)=A_0+zA_1+z^2A_2+\dots$$
and
$$A^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{z^s}(X_0+zX_1+z^2X_2+\dots)$$ into the equation
$A(z)A^{-1}(z)=I,$ we obtain the set of equations
$$\sum_{i=0}^kA_iX_{k-i}=\delta_{ks}I,\quad k=0,1,\dots\tag{1}$$
where $\,\delta_{ks}\,$ is the Kronecker delta. And if we substitute the above series into the equation  $A^{-1}(z)A(z)=I,$ we obtain the set of equations
$$\sum_{i=0}^k X_{k-i}A_i=\delta_{ks}I,\quad k=0,1,\dots\tag{2}$$
How can one prove that the set of equations $(1), (2)$ are equivalent?

I would be grateful for any hints or solutions for this problem, because all my attempts are bad.

Comment: Maybe you could show your attempts?

Comment: Can we have some context here?  Is $A(z)$ a matrix?  A linear operator on some space?  Are the series assumed to converge? Note that for bounded linear operators on infinite-dimensional spaces, having left and right inverses is not equivalent.